# How to send and receive string using MPI

Tags: c++, c, mpi

I am trying to send and recieve string using MPI but results are hopless.

Send function:

```
MPI_Send(&result, result.size(), MPI_CHAR, 0, 0, MPI_COMM_WORLD);
```

And the recv function:

```
    MPI_Recv(&result,      /* message buffer */
        128,                 /* one data item */
        MPI_CHAR,        /* of type char real */
        MPI_ANY_SOURCE,    /* receive from any sender */
        MPI_ANY_TAG,       /* any type of message */
        MPI_COMM_WORLD,    /* default communicator */
        &status);          /* info about the received message */
```

Where result is a string.

I didn't get any error but program doesn't want to finish.

Answer (score 18, accepted):

The address of a `std::string` is not the same as address of the underlying C string, so sending should be fixed like this:

```
MPI_Send(result.c_str(), result.size(), MPI_CHAR, 0, 0, MPI_COMM_WORLD);
```

Receiving cannot be done as you tried to do it. You need a buffer (an array of `char`), which you will pass to `MPI_Recv` and use it later to create a `std::string` instance. To get a length of the string received use `MPI_Get_count` - this you should pass along the pointer to buffer to `std::string` constructor.

In order to avoid preallocating the buffer and allow it to receive a string of any size you should call `MPI_Probe` and `MPI_Get_count` to get the length first. Knowing the length you can allocate the buffer with the exact size which is necessary, and only then call `MPI_Recv`.

If this sounds a bit complicated then you can consider using [BOOST MPI wrappers](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_55_0/doc/html/mpi.html).

Comment: +1, beat me to it. Regarding the receive, if `result` is known to have a large enough buffer (previously created), he can use `&result[0]` to get a non-const pointer to the internal buffer.

Comment: If `result` is a `std::string` then `&result[0]` should be the same as `result.c_str()`, except it is non-const. I would personally use the former, with a `const_cast`. I see what you mean here, passing a preallocated `std::string` can work with `MPI_Recv`, but it will fail if the string contains `0`, for example, so care should be taken...

Comment: When I change argument to array of char, everything works fine. Thx guys. :)

Comment: Should not you use MPI_Send(result.c_str(), result.size() + 1, MPI_CHAR, 0, 0, MPI_COMM_WORLD); in order to incorporate string termination sign '\0' ?

Comment: @piokuc MPI_Send(result.c_str(), result.size(), MPI_CHAR, 0, 0, MPI_COMM_WORLD); gives compiler error telling the first argument with type of const char* is incompatable with parameter void*. How can I solve that?

Comment: @Nurlan I know this is very late, but your problem is that you declared `result` as `const`. However, by definition of a Send/Recv pair, you need to be able to change `result` on the receiving end. So it cannot be a `const std::string`, but rather a non-const `std::string`.

Answer (score -1):

I was having similar problem where I had to pass a string between two processes in MPI C. My solution, aligned to your problem, is the following:

```
MPI_Send(&result, strlen(result)+1, MPI_CHAR, 1, 0, MPI_COMM_WORLD); // Destination: Process 1
```

On the other side, process 0 will have the following MPI_Recv function:

```
MPI_Recv(&result, 100, MPI_CHAR, 0, 0, MPI_COMM_WORLD, MPI_STATUS_IGNORE); // Source: Process 0 and considering 100 as the maximum string length
```

`<string.h>` has to be added in the header.