# C++ MPI - Scatter array of strings

Tags: c++, arrays, string, mpi

I need to Scatter my string array. The problem is, I'm not sure, how to do it correctly, I'm used to it only in C.

My program has the array `scatterArr` which contains several strings (one for every process, so this number is changing). String length is changing too - my program loads text from a file, so, it depends on the word count.

Example of `scatterArr` (just for this example I assigned strings manually):

```
int world_size = 4; // number of processes

string * scatterArr = new string[world_size];
scatterArr[0] = "Hello;How;";
scatterArr[1] = "I;are;";
scatterArr[2] = "am;you;";
scatterArr[3] = "John;"; // only one word loaded
```

And now `Scatter()`:

```
int arrCharCount = 21;

char * recvArr = new char[ ??? ]; // I'm not sure what size to expect
COMM_WORLD.Scatter( scatterArr, arrCharCount, CHAR, recvArr, ???, CHAR, 0 );
```

Here I'm not sure about using `char *` as a `recvArr` type (maybe `string` would be better?) and about the size I should allocate for my `recvArr` array.

So, could you please help me with this and explain it, if possible, more thoroughly? I've found [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22425207/mpi-scatter-only-sending-first-element) question, but I've not understood, how can I determine the size of `recvArr` when I don't know the exact number of CHARS which will come.

Comment: You cannot scatter strings like this because they are not guaranteed to be stored at adjacent addresses.

Comment: Ok, how should I scatters string like this? :D

Comment: Well, you could for example, allocate a N*M array and assume that every row of that array is a separate string and then you would scatter the array row-wise.